# ASP.NET Session won't expire

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, web-config

I have the following in the web.config

```
<sessionState cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" cookieless="false" mode="InProc" timeout="1" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"/>
```

however, after 1 min, the session won't expire.
what can cause this?

thanks

Comment: Show the part of the web.config.

Comment: Sessions expire only if the user stops interacting with the site.

Comment: Not quite true Oded, see below.

Comment: Thanks Oded (nice name... mine is Oded too) -> apparently i had the AJAX calls (validating the session) that were shorter than the session lifetime... so each ajax extended the session

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using forms authentication. Sliding expiration is true by default, so if you look at the slidingExpiration attribute of your web.config forms element you may get the behaviour you're looking for. If false, it will expire after the specified amount of time since it was set.

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx